# qt file menu with vertical separator to make recent column

Tags: qt, qmainwindow

I am new to Qt and trying to make a file menu which should have two column one with File, Save, Save etc and next column that shows recent file. It is similar like microsoft word 2007 have the file menu. I haven't found and vertical separator in file menu of Qmainwindow. Is there any way to implement such layout with file menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't do the thing with QMenu but I removed menubar and made a widget which looks like required layout.